# Bootstrap navbar icon-bar is not working

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use bootstrap navbar, it is collapsing when screen size is reduced, but It is not working(Menus are not appearing) when I am clicking it.
Here is my HTML

```
    <div class="nav-holder">
  <div ng-controller="NavbarCtrl">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
                  data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">MENU</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
          <div ng-repeat="menu in menus">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav menu-group">
              <li ng-if="!hasSubMenus(menu)">
                <a ui-sref="{{menu.state}}">{{menu.title}}</a>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown" ng-if="hasSubMenus(menu)">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"
                   data-toggle="dropdown"
                   role="button"
                   aria-haspopup="true"
                   aria-expanded="false">{{menu.title}}<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li ng-repeat="subMenu in menu.subMenus">
                    <a ui-sref="{{subMenu.state}}">{{subMenu.title}}</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my less file:

```
.nav-holder {
  text-align: left;
  .menu-group {
    margin-left: 7%;
  }
}
```

Here is my code along with angular in jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/suryaSharma/3e8hkys9/

Comment: Have you tried to use a standard navbar without adding angular? Is it possible angular is causing this issue?

Comment: Where is your angular code?  Something must be providing `menus` and `hasSubMenus` on your scope object.  Can you add that, preferably along with a working code demo that showcases the problem?

Comment: Has any solution worked for you?

Comment: @MethodMan I tried after removing angular but problem remains same

Comment: @KyleMit, I updated question with angular code on jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening and closing the menu items requires bootstrap.js and bootstrap.js requires jquery.js. So, add the jquery.js file.

You can open the console and check, it says.

> Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery

--EDIT--

Here's the updated [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/devkickstart/3e8hkys9/1/).

updated code for it to work fine.

```
<div class="nav-holder" ng-app="fsdoApp"> // missing ng-app

</div>

angular.module('fsdoApp', []) // missing [] for initiating module
```

Answer (score 0):

This had happened to me over at: http://v1.2-alpha.joshmurray.eu/

What I did to fix this was... Simply make sure the `icon-bar` class *wasn't* transparent, because when I was editing my `navbar` and `navbar-default` I wanted to have a transparent background, so I simply done:

```
navbar-default {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

And this made everything transparent, except from the links and stuff.

Here is my CSS for fixing my problem with the 'hidden' `icon-bar` for **Bootstrap 3.3.6**:

```
.icon-bar {
    background-color: white;
}
```

Make sure you add this either into the `<head>` like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Document - hidden icon-bar</title>

        <style>
            .icon-bar {
                background-color: white;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
</html>
```

Or use an external stylesheet, like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Document - hidden icon-bar</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/stlyes.css">
    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: No it is not the case, I tried what you said, but it isn't working